# How to send request from server to client using GKSession?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gksession

I want to know how can I send request from server to client using GKSession?
The reference class for GKSession say the following:

```
- (void)connectToPeer:(NSString *)peerID withTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout Parameters peerID The string that
```

> identifies the peer to connect to.
>
> timeout The amount of time to wait before canceling the connection
>   attempt.
>
> Discussion
>
> When your application is acting as a client, it calls this method to
>   connect to an available peer it discovered. When your application
>   calls this method, a request is transmitted to the remote peer, who
>   chooses whether to accept or reject the connection request.

What should I use if I am server?

Answer (score 0):

As a server you make yourself available for client connections with

```
peer2peerSession.available = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating a GKSession instance as a server:

```
[[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:sessionID displayName:@"Chris" sessionMode : GKSessionModeServer];
```

Here is an example of how to create a GKSession as a client:

```
[[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:sessionID displayName:@"Angel" sessionMode : GKSessionModeClient];
```

GKSessionModePeer will create a GKSession instance that will both advertise itself as a server, and at the same time look for advertising servers (in other words act as a client searching for servers).

You then need to set a delegate for your GKSession object, after-which the delegate needs to implement the following delegate method:

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState : (GKPeerConnectionState)state
```

Within the above method you will receive messages from the session that a device has become available, became unavailable, connected, etc.

To send a request:

```
[_session connectToPeer:peerID withTimeout:_session.disconnectTimeout];
```

To accept a request:

```
[_session acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:&error];
```

There is a lot of code involved and the best tutorial for you to understand everything is located here: [Simple Card Playing game using GKSession](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1)